# querySelector is unable to access passed id

Tags: javascript, html, queryselector

```
<div id="page1">
               block1
        </div>
        <div id="page2">
             block2
        </div>
        <div id="page3">
            block3
        </div>
```

I am trying to access the id of the div by using following function, but it does not work.

```
           function  aa(page)
              {
                  document.querySelector('#${page}').style.display='block';
              }
```

I am getting the following error:
`'querySelector' on 'Document': '#${page}' is not a valid selector.`

Comment: you probably meant to use backticks `\`` instead of single quotes `'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) enclosed by backticks instead of single quotes which delimit a normal string.

```
document.querySelector(`#${page}`)
```